# What's wrong with the following code?

Tags: c

```
int *intialize(void) 
{
    int value[64];

    for ( int i = 0; i < 64 ; i++)
    {
        value[i] = i;

       return value;   
    }

}  

int main( )
{
    int * p;

    p = intialize();
    p[32] = 100;
    printf("%d", p[32]);

    return 0;
}
```

Above is the sample code that was asked to me in an interview. Though I failed to find error and obviously rejected, I am curious to know what is exactly wrong with this code.

Comment: Before we go any further, what did you think was wrong with it?

Comment: I guess , is there is anything wrong with memory ? may be malloc?

Comment: @samprat - No, you are returning the reference of a local variable.

Comment: Maybe malloc? I can't see malloc in there. Can you?

Comment: @samprat - May I know the company name you attended to ? Just curious.

Comment: so what should be the correct way ?

Comment: @samprat Correct way to do what? We don't know what the goal of the program is. The goal of this program is to catch out people that don't know enough about C to recognise stack pointers being returned from functions.

Comment: @Mahesh, for knowledge sake, I have used local variable to return the value in main function. So whats wrong in that case.

Comment: @Mahesh has it right.  FYI, every compiler I know throws a warning for that, so it probably wouldn't hurt to at least try compiling it next time before asking SO :-)

Comment: @David Heffernan, Thanks for info. I will look into stack pointers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Please don't change what the code does by correcting it.  We can probably assume it was in error but that's part of the question.  If it's just formatting, that's fine.

Comment: @Karl, I have  complied the prog and it throws segmentation fault.

Comment: @samprat Have it your way then, return on the first time around the loop!! There's no point initializing it anyway, since it's garbage as soon as you return it out of the function!!

Comment: @samprat, correct way is to use `int* value = (int*)malloc(64*sizeof(int));` inside initialize.

Comment: @Jeff M   I assumed that the return in the middle of the loop was just a transliteration error as surely the point of the exercise was to test if the candidate knew about the folly of returning pointers to the stack. But maybe the interviewers really had both dumb errors in the code!

Comment: @samprat, it will compile successfully, but it should generate a warning, unless you have a really bad compiler.  Always heed the warnings.

Comment: @Karl, are you sure about the cast ? Question is tagged as `C`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Indeed, but that's better left for samprat to correct, not us.  Or at least have him confirm in a comment first before changing it ourselves.  He probably knowingly wrote it that way.  We should give him the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @Jeff OK, OK. This is how wiki works though huh?

Comment: @David, indeed the `return` inside the `for` makes no sense, but I think they would want him to ask something about it, in case he mentioned the solution to the problem, and then another problem was asked on top of that piece of code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I say it's wiki _after_ the author has made his point.  It doesn't help anyone if you change the meaning of that point along the way.  And AFAIK, that has always been the policy here, to improve the _presentation_ of the question or answer and never change the meaning of it unless the original author declares it open for changes.

Comment: @Jeff OK. Must resist urge to correct code. Must resist urge to correct code. Must resist urge to correct code. Right, I think I've got it now! Thanks!

Comment: Well guys, I am pretty sure that the return stmt was inside the for. I  got feeling that its wrong but couldn't able to justify why its wrong?

Comment: @Muggen, `malloc` returns a `void*`, which the compiler will implicitly cast to an `int*` for the assignment.  I like to show the cast explicitly for style purposes.

Comment: @samprat, as I said in a previous comment, I guess they were about to ask you to do something else with that array when you would provide the `malloc()` solution. The values of the array at this moment are indeterminate besides `value[0]` which you know is `0`.

Comment: @Muggen, true. They just ask me why this code will not work and I failed to give satisfying answer

Comment: @samprat, doesn't matter. next time :) I somehow sympathize with you. I will be in the job market too in 6 months. Good luck!

Comment: @samprat did you remember the code, or did you take away a copy of it?

Comment: @Jeff @muggen @everyone_else sorry for messing up with the edits, I can see that was inappropriate and unhelpful, I will learn!!

Comment: @david, I did remember the code correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int value[64];  

for ( int i = 0; i < 64 ; i++)  
{
    value[i] = i;  
}
return value;
```

`value` is defined in the local scope of `initialize()` and also, if you could assume that was valid, you return the memory location on the first iteration, hence making the contents of `value[]` garbage after `value[0]`.

When you define a variable in the local scope, the variable ceases to exist when the function reaches termination. Returning a pointer to a local variable invokes Undefined Behaviour cause you access (and use) memory you should not.

Undefined Behaviour mate `;)`

---

If you want to make it correct you should do something like :

```
int  * result = malloc(sizeof(int)* 64);  
if(!result)
    return 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < 64 ; i++)  
{
    result[i] = i;  
}
return result;
```

And also check in your `main()` if `initialize()` returns `0` or not (AKA if `malloc()` succeeded or Failed) and if the return value was not `0` make sure you `free()` the memory.

```
int main( )
{
    int * p;

    p = intialize();
    if(p)
    {
         p[32] = 100;
         printf("%d", p[32]);
         free(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You could also have the `free()` outside the `if` clause, cause doing a `free(0)` is safe.

Comment: I think thats the solution of the problem. Let me check it . I will keep u guys informed.Thanks again to all the folks for such a quick response

Comment: On a sidenote : In `C` you should not cast the result of `malloc()`. More : http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html

Comment: Thanks a lot , The program works fine. I have concept about malloc but i just scummed to apply it.

Answer (score 2):

'intialize' is a typo (though it is a consistent typo, so will compile).

Did I get it right?

Comment: Also, the code is self-modifying.  Everytime I refresh, it's changed :-(

Comment: I read this and almost +1ed it for imploring the OP to write "initialise". Then I saw the typo you were actually correcting and felt disappointed.

Comment: hehe, the OP may be American, so I had to let that pass ;-)